# some questions about the symbol of expressing continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\to R$. If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ , and $[c,d]$ is a smaller domain than $[a,b]$ and is contained in $[a,b]$ , then can we say that $f$ is continuous on $[c,d]$? Or we have to modify the symbol of function to a restricted function on $[c,d]$ which is in this form: $f\mid _{[c,d]}$ is continuous on $[c,d]$?

Thanks for explanation!

Comment: I don't think we need to modify the symbol.

Comment: It i generally understood that when $S$ is a subset of  dom$(f),$  the expression "$f$ is continuous on S" is synonymous with "$ f|_S$ is continuous."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can be said to be continuous at any point in its domain, or on any subset on its domain. Therefore, if $[c,d]\subseteq[a,b]$, the continuous function $f:[a,b]\to R$ may rightly be said to be continuous on $[c,d]$. Indeed, some functions are not continuous over their entire domain, and so it is useful to point out the subset on which the function is continuous.